# Failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error) in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like my code to fetch a image from the database therefore
 I call the display.php. I got an interval server error in response.

```
  <?require_once"db.php";
  $sql="select * from image";

  $result=mysql_query($sql);

   if($result)
     {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
      echo"<img src=display.php?id=".$row['id']."/>";
        }
       }
          else
          {
       echo"error";
             }
           ?>


          display.php

          <?require_once"db.php";
           $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
          $sql="select photo,imagetype from image where id='$id'";
         $result=mysql_query($sql);
              if($result)
            {
              $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
           $type="Content-type:".row['imagetype'];
             header($type);
         echo $row['photo'];
              }
           else
           {
        echo "error";
        }


           ?>
```

This is another page here, where I get the image from the database based on id. What is the error on this page? When I run show.php it shows the failed to relocate internal error 400. I tried to fix it but failed.

Comment: `status 500 internal server error` usually means that you've got a syntax error or some other fatal error in your PHP code. Turn on PHP's error reporting to see what it is (or look in the server logs).

Comment: Off topic, but there are several serious issues with this code. You're putting the `$id` value into your SQL query without doing any kind of escaping: this means you are wide open to having your server hacked with a SQL injection attack. You're also using obsolete PHP techniques, such as `mysql_query()` and related functions. The mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated; you should use a more modern DB API such as `mysqli` or `PDO`.